# How to make the array size a ReadLine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a sorting algorithm and asking the user to input the array size is a must. I am a beginner in C# so I don't have any idea how to do that.

This is the idea that came to my mind, but I'm having an error.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter how many elements you want to be sorted:");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] MyArray= new int[a] {""};
```

Visual Studio says that 'a constant value is expected'. How could I make the array length a ReadLine? My goal is for the user to decide which array length they want the program to show and that the elements inside the array would be system generated based on the array length that the user chose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initialise an array like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays):

```
int[] MyArray= new int[a];
```

But, I would also point out, that you could use a dynamic collection (such as a list), then you don't need to ask up front how many items, you just keep adding items until the user decides to stop.

```
ICollection<int> myCollection = new List<int>();
myCollection.Add(1);
myCollection.Add(1);
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, I tried this and it works <3

Answer (score 1):

The type of your array is int but you are trying to initialize it with an empty string. In C# you can declare an array in a few ways. You can declare it by providing a size as in:

```
int[] myArray = new int[size];
```

And initialize the values later.

An alternative is to instantly intialize it with values like this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Note that when using the second option, you shouldn't provied the size as the compiler will infere it.